# Using edgelist with 3 columns in txt.file

Tags: python, networkx

I'm new to NetworkX and I have a problem. I have .txt file containing lots of data in 3 columns separated by tab like this:

```
1   21   \N
2   61   \N
2   62   1201231
50  11   54432
```

How can I use `read.edgelist('data.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)` using only first 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

A solution which does not use `nx.read_edgelist()` but the default constructor is as follows.

```
>>> with open("file.txt") as f:
...     g = nx.Graph([line.split()[:2] for line in f])
... 
>>> g.edges()
EdgeView([('1', '21'), ('2', '61'), ('2', '62'), ('50', '11')])
```

If the nodetype is required to be integer you can convert to `int` while reading the file.

For example,

```
[tuple(map(int,line.split()[:2])) for line in f]
```